# Windows permission problem

Tags: windows

Hi I need to save a file in `c:/windows/system32/drivers` folder. But when I try to save it is not allowing me. I tried to change permissions by right clicking that folder and modifying in the security tab. Yet it is not allowing me to change. what should be done in order to gain access privilege??

Comment: For goodness sake why do you need to put files in the *operating system* folders? There's a reason why there are non-administrator restrictions on them in the first place!

Comment: I am trying to install INSTANT RAILS which requires to add an IP to the hosts file of windows. @In silico

Comment: So you want to *modify* an existing file (in this case, the hosts file) rather than adding new files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried editing the hosts file using Notepad launched [via the "Run as administrator" command](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923947)?

According to the knowledge base article, if you get an error message that looks like this:

> Access to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ hosts was denied

Or like this:

> Cannot create the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.
>   Make sure that the path and file name are correct.

Try this:

> Start →  All Programs →  Accessories →  right-click "Notepad" →  Run as administrator →  Modify hosts file appropriately →  Save

### Note:

Adding/modifying the files in the system directories is a **very, very, very bad idea**. It is acceptable for this specific case of the hosts file, but in general **adding and modifying files in the system folders is verboten**.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Are you an admin on the system?  If not, then you can't edit permissions of system folders.  (And, depending on the version of Windows, it may be difficult/obtuse even for an Admin to do it.)

Long answer: You shouldn't be doing this.  That path (and many like it) is used by the OS for its own design and its own purposes.  You probably don't want to mess with it.  You may unintentionally break something.  It's also a very unintuitive place to store things that aren't part of the OS installation.  What are you trying to store there and why?  If it's part of an application, it should be stored with that application.  If it's something for a user, it should be stored in the user's space.  Etc.

**Edit:** Based on your comment in response to your question: The `hosts` file is actually one level down from there, in the `etc` folder that's under `drivers`.  You shouldn't have to change any folder-level permissions to edit that.  If you can't edit the file, try to change its permissions.  If you can't do that, it doesn't sound like you have admin rights, which you'll probably need.

Comment: am trying to install INSTANT RAILS which needs to add an IP address to hosts file of windows... and yes, I am the administrator of the system

Comment: I am the administrator of the system for sure. Am saying on the basis tht i ve power to add / remove users etc and all admin stuff. But still i am not able to save the hosts folder in etc folder. So is it that i was having a wrong perception tht i was an admin?

Comment: @CHID: It's possible.  I've never had problems editing that file as a local admin (not the Administrator account, just local admin rights on my account) in any version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving it to another place (Documents perhaps?) and then copy it there.  It will ask you if you're sure you want to do it, but at this point say yes and it'll copy the file there.  Windows won't let you simply create a file in c:/windows/system32/drivers for obvious reasons.

And I don't need to tell you to be careful, do I?  Hmm??

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and opening notepad by right clicking it and selecting "run as administrator" I then opened and edited the hosts file and it allowed me to save where it did not before.